# .then(Response => SyntaxError: Unexpected token ., in Vue js

Tags: vue.js

I'm currently learning Vue and following a Udemy course. My empty Vue project is however a bit more strict in notation than my teachers. So while I'm trying to figure it all out, I'm also sometimes getting unexpected token errors.

I don't really understand why I am getting a unexpected token error on .then.
This might be something very simple that I don't yet see as a mistake.

I checked everything to see if everything has a closing tag, has commas and semicolons.

```
actions: {
    signIn({ commit }, payload) {
      Vue.http.post(`${FbAuth}/verifyPassword?key=${FbApiKey}`, {
        ...payload,
        returnSecureToken: true,
      }),
      .then( response => response.json())
      .then( authData =>  {
        console.log(authData);
      }),
    },
  },
```

It should pass the signin action and check my firebase database for the needed credentials.

Comment: You have a comma that is not supposed to be there, just before the first `then`. Remove it, and the syntax should be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a comma before the dot.
Try this follow code:

```
    actions: {
        signIn({ commit }, payload) {
          Vue.http.post(`${FbAuth}/verifyPassword?key=${FbApiKey}`, {
            ...payload,
            returnSecureToken: true,
          })
          .then( response => response.json())
          .then( authData =>  {
            console.log(authData);
          }),
        },
      },
```